# How to find pageindex of active page in Access 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I need to find the index of an activepage in acces, in order for me to program a button to switch beetwen pages. (1 forward/1 backwar). The code i use is:

```
Private Sub forward()
dim curIndex as int
curIndex = activepageindex ??
For Each ctl In Form.Controls
   If ctl.ControlType = 124 Then
       If ctl.PageIndex = curIndex+1 Then
            ctl.Enabled = True
            ctl.SetFocus
        Else
            ctl.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the page of a TabControl?

If so, you need the Value property:

```
curIndex = Me.TabControl.Value
```